# Setting timeout function based on animation delay

Tags: javascript, css, timeout, css-animations, settimeout

I need to set my `.screens` to be `display: none` until the point when its animation starts. Each one has a separate `animation-delay` so what I hope to achieve is that a function will check how long the animation delay is and that will then determine the length of the `setTimeout` function.

Example:
If `.screens` has an animation delay of 3 seconds, then after 3 seconds I want display to change from `none` to `block`.

Code of the function I have written so far is below:

```
var screens = document.getElementsByClassName('screen');
for (var i=0;i<screens.length;i++){
    if (screens[i].style.animationDelay >=0){
        setTimeout(function(){
           this.style.display = "block"; 
        }, this.style.animationDelay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot `animate` the *state/value* from `none` to `block` of the `display` *property*, you can instead do it with the `visibility: hidden` / `visibility: visible` pair, and of course you could also do it with the `opacity: 0` / `opacity: 1`:

```css
.screen {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: animate forwards;
}

.screen:first-child {animation-delay: 1s}
.screen:nth-child(2) {animation-delay: 2s}
.screen:nth-child(3) {animation-delay: 3s}

@keyframes animate {
  to {visibility: visible}
}
```

```html
<div class="screen">1</div>
<div class="screen">2</div>
<div class="screen">3</div>
```

Then you can just target the `.screen` *elements* with the `:nth-child` or `:nth-of-type` *selectors*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. (You can skip the first part, it is there just to generate `screens` with random `animationDelay`)

```js
const generateScreens = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'screen';
    el.style.animationDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 's';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
  }
}

generateScreens();

// code that you have asked for starts here
const screens = document.getElementsByClassName('screen');
[...screens].forEach(item => {
  const delay = item.style.animationDelay.slice(0, item.style.animationDelay.length - 1);
  setTimeout(() => {
    item.style.display = 'block';
  }, delay * 1000);
});
```

```css
div.screen {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
```